# Why CALayer shadow renders incorrect in manually created CGContext?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, calayer, cgcontext

On a 2x device, rendering a `CALayer` with `shadowRadius = r` and `shadowOffset = (x, y)` in a manually created `CGContext` using `CALayer.render(in:)` produces a shadow with `shadowRadius = r/2` and `shadowOffset = (x/2, -y/2)`, as if transformation matrix is not set up and still in the initial state even though it is already correctly set up.

If the context is set up using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` the result is correct.

Even if I create my own context based on the context created with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` the result is still wrong.

```
// Manually created context produces wrong shadow.
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue | CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue)
if let ctx1 = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(view.bounds.width * UIScreen.main.scale), height: Int(view.bounds.height * UIScreen.main.scale), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: Int(4 * view.bounds.width * UIScreen.main.scale), space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue) {
    ctx1.scaleBy(x: UIScreen.main.scale, y: -UIScreen.main.scale)
    ctx1.translateBy(x: 0, y: -view.bounds.height)

    view.layer.render(in: ctx1)
    guard let image = ctx1.makeImage() else {
        return
    }
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(cgImage: image), nil, nil, nil)
}

// Context created using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions produces correct shadow.
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
if let ctx2 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
    view.layer.render(in: ctx2)
    guard let image = ctx2.makeImage() else {
        return
    }
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(cgImage: image), nil, nil, nil)

    // Manually created context with configurations copied from the "good" context still produces wrong shadow.
    if let ctx3 = CGContext(data: nil, width: ctx2.width, height: ctx2.height, bitsPerComponent: ctx2.bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: ctx2.bytesPerRow, space: ctx2.colorSpace!, bitmapInfo: ctx2.bitmapInfo.rawValue) {
        ctx3.concatenate(ctx2.ctm)

        view.layer.render(in: ctx3)
        guard let image = ctx3.makeImage() else {
            return
        }
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(cgImage: image), nil, nil, nil)
    }
}
```

I compared and made sure these configurations of all the 3 contexts are the same:

- width
- height
- bitsPerComponent
- bytesPerRow
- colorSpace
- bitmapInfo
- ctm
- interpolationQuality

Here is the [sample app](https://cloudup.com/cWkk8BsFJkO).

Answer (score 0):

[In the Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html)

It states the following about shadows:

> **Shadows**
>
> The direction a shadow falls from its object is specified by an offset
>   value, and the meaning of that offset is a convention of a drawing
>   framework. In UIKit, positive x and y offsets make a shadow go down
>   and to the right of an object. In Core Graphics, positive x and y
>   offsets make a shadow go up and to the right of an object. Flipping
>   the CTM to align an object with the default coordinate system of UIKit
>   does not affect the object’s shadow, and so a shadow does not
>   correctly track its object. To get it to track correctly, you must
>   modify the offset values appropriately for the current coordinate
>   system.

I am currently facing the same problem in an app that I am working on. It seems as though you may need to set the shadow offsets manually.